# pymongo db.collection_names() return empty list

Tags: mongodb, collections, pymongo

I am using the following code to connect to database and for each database list all collections:

```
conMongo =MongoClient(connect,27017)
listOfDBs = conMongo.database_names()

for i in listOfDBs:
    db = conMongo[i]
    print db
    print db.collection_names(): 

 conMongo.disconnect()
```

The connection to the database doesn't have any problem and the list of databases can be printed.

But the db.collection_names() prints empty lists, although there are many collections in each database.

Comment: It worked when I tried it after removing the trailing `:` on that line.

Comment: sorry that trailing `:` was a typo mistake even without that it is not working for me. I am using Mongo v3.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by updating pymongo package with:

```
easy_install --upgrade pymongo
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old bug (PYTHON-790, SERVER-16224) dating back at least to 2014.

A system using a pre-2.8 version of `pymongo` (such as Ubuntu 14, which is stuck at `pymongo` 2.6.3) to interrogate a 2.8 or later MongoDB server will see its `collection_names()` method always return an empty list.

There is no simple workaround, and you'll be reduced to testing for collection existence using the following command:

```py
database['collection'].count() > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the database name

MongoDB is a case-sensitive database so the database name in the code and the server should be exactly the same.
For me, my DB name was `db_name` and I looked for `db-name` in my code so it didn't work

Hoped it helped :)